# why does NETGEAR Stora NAS constantly prompt me for my login details?

Tags: nas

I have a NETGEAR Stora plugged into my router and made the static ip address of mac address and works well. This stora only is accessable from our LAN/Home office/2 Users.

I have set it up to look for the static ip address in the 'Stora Agent'

I try to log in and and it comes up with a dialog saying 'Local connection impossible. Do you want to try remote connection instead'? If I say No then it does nothing if I say Yes then it throws an 'Unexpected Error'

Why does it insist on prompting me for my login details? I want to remove the security on it. I want it to trust all requests.

Is this a bad setup or use of the NAS for me? Am I missing something?

The mapped network drives also keep disappearing in Windows.

What am I doing wrong?